# how to access ubuntu-touch using openssh server ? getting login prompt, not accepting password

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

i have installed ubuntu touch on my nexux 4 from devel channel. how can i enable ssh access.

ssh is running. but when i try to connect to that IP, i am getting error like no authentication mechanism or something like hat

Regards,
Ben

Comment: Do you want to SSH to the phone or from the phone? Do you have openssh-server installed?

Comment: I want to ssh to the phone. yes openssh server is installed by default and it's running

Comment: this is the error message i am getting while puttying http://snag.gy/pn7Tb.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Password authentication is disabled on the phone, only public key authentication is available. This means that you have to store your public key on the phone. See my answer on this for a few more details:

[Can't SSH into Ubuntu Touch device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/563573/cant-ssh-into-ubuntu-touch-device)